# Injecting viewmodel dependency with dagger 2

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am having issues injecting a dependency into my viewModel. I keep getting Cannot create an instance of class ....viewModel.UserProfileViewModel. I have been trying to figure out this issue. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Here is my code. I have seen in other questions that this is usually caused by having a parameter in the constructor of the viewmodel, and creating a factory should resolve the issue. but it did not seem to work quite as well for me. I must be missing something.

Thanks!

```
 App component:

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, ViewModelModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance Builder application(Application application);
        ApplicationComponent build();
    }
}
=====================================================
App module:

@Module
public class AppModule {
    Application mApplication;


    public AppModule(Application application){
        mApplication = application;
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application providesApplication(){
        return mApplication;
    }
}

===========================================================
ViewFactory

@Singleton
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> viewModels) {
        this.creators = viewModels;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);

        if (creator == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                    creator = entry.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
        }
        try {
            return (T) creator.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

===========================================================
View key

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}

========================================================
View Module

@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(UserProfileViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindUserViewModel(UserProfileViewModel userViewModel);
}

===========================================================
view model class

public class UserProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private UserRepository mUserRepository;
    private LiveData<User> mObservableUser;

    @Inject
    public UserProfileViewModel(@NonNull UserRepository userRepo){
        this.mUserRepository = userRepo;
    }


    public void init(String userId){
        if (this.mObservableUser != null) {
            return;
        }
        mObservableUser = mUserRepository.getUser(userId);
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser() {
        return this.mObservableUser;
    }

}

 ====================================================
in fragment

 viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(UserProfileViewModel.class);
        viewModel.init(mUserId);
```

Stack trace 22:08:49.677 19211-19211/nonso.android.nonso E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nonso.android.nonso, PID: 19211
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class nonso.android.nonso.viewModel.UserProfileViewModel
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:153)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:210)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
        at nonso.android.nonso.ui.fragments.ProfileFragment.setUp(ProfileFragment.java:133)
        at nonso.android.nonso.ui.fragments.ProfileFragment.onActivityCreated(ProfileFragment.java:122)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2355)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1451)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:151)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:210) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102) 
        at nonso.android.nonso.ui.fragments.ProfileFragment.setUp(ProfileFragment.java:133) 
        at nonso.android.nonso.ui.fragments.ProfileFragment.onActivityCreated(ProfileFragment.java:122) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2355) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1451) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Where is `UserRepository` supposed to come from?

Comment: UserRepository is to be injected by Dagger at runtime, so there is just one instance of it in the application

Comment: okay but there is no way for me to verify this, nor the exact error you are getting :D

Comment: I have seen people have similar issues like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194579/android-viewmodel-has-no-zero-argument-constructor/49087002#49087002. I followed the answer but i still seem to be missing something

Comment: Show your full stack trace.