# How to inject Repository into ViewModel?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I am using Dagger 2 and I have a `DiComponent` defined as follows:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        ApplicationModule.class,
        PreferenceModule.class,
        RetrofitModule.class,
        RoomModule.class,
})
public interface DiComponent  {

    void inject(SplashScreen activity);
    void inject(Home activity);

    void inject(FYViewModel viewModel);
    void inject(CFViewModel viewModel);
}
```

This is the `FYViewModel.class`:

```
public class FYViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = FYViewModel.class.getSimpleName();

    @Inject
    public FYRepository mRepository;

    private LiveData<List<Post>> mPostList;

    public FYViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        Log.d(TAG, "FYViewModel: " + mRepository);
//        mPostList = mRepository.getAllPosts();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Post>> getAllPosts() {
        return mPostList;
    }

    public void fetchNextData(int page) {
        mRepository.fetchNextPosts(page);
    }

}
```

However, the `mRepository` variable is always null.

How can I use Dagger 2 to inject Repositroy into my ViewModels?

Comment: DiComponent should have FYRepository inside, which  you already did for other, follow the same.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I do have a `providesRepository` method implemented inside `RoomModule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend setting up a ViewModel factory for this.

Here is a good read:

https://proandroiddev.com/viewmodel-with-dagger2-architecture-components-2e06f06c9455

Set that up, add an @Provides for the repository class, then you can inject your repository.

Comment: I ended up doing this in Java using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49087002/2231031