# Why my app in kotlin crashes when calling a coroutine?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, coroutine

I am trying to call a function in a Fragment that is in my ViewModel but it crashes everytime its called and I don´t know why.
Here it´s the code:

Call to a coroutine:

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
                courseViewModel.repository.insertCourse(getData())
            }
            Navigation.findNavController(it).popBackStack()
        }
```

The code of the function:
`suspend fun insertCourse(course: Course) = courseDAO.insertCourse(course)`

If I don´t use the coroutine and just `courseViewModel.repository.insertCourse(getData())` i get an error that says I have to call this function from other suspend function or a coroutine.

This is the error:

```
2022-03-20 13:33:43.893 28396-28437/com.example.cursosmvvm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.cursosmvvm, PID: 28396
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class domain.CourseViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:188)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:238)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:169)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:139)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:44)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:31)
        at ui.NewCourseFragment.getCourseViewModel(NewCourseFragment.kt:23)
        at ui.NewCourseFragment.access$getCourseViewModel(NewCourseFragment.kt:20)
        at ui.NewCourseFragment$onViewCreated$1$1.invokeSuspend(NewCourseFragment.kt:58)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<domain.CourseViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:186)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:238) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:169) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:139) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:44) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:31) 
        at ui.NewCourseFragment.getCourseViewModel(NewCourseFragment.kt:23) 
        at ui.NewCourseFragment.access$getCourseViewModel(NewCourseFragment.kt:20) 
        at ui.NewCourseFragment$onViewCreated$1$1.invokeSuspend(NewCourseFragment.kt:58) 
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

And my ViewModel is this:

```
class CourseViewModel(val repository: CourseRepository): ViewModel(){
```

In the fragment where I call the coroutine I declarate it like this: `private val courseViewModel: CourseViewModel by activityViewModels()`

Comment: Let's see the stack trace, please post it

Comment: Maybe `lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)`? Are objects initialized (not null)? Also it's strange that you have a direct access to `repository` of ViewModel. Maybe you should make it private and call `insertCourse`.

Comment: Any call to database must be done outside of the main thread.
Try what @CoolMind suggested.

Comment: Well, crash log says you haven't created the ViewModel. `java.lang.Class<domain.CourseViewModel> has no zero argument constructor`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194579/android-viewmodel-has-no-zero-argument-constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't need to clutter up your fragment code with a coroutine in this situation. Your ViewModel and/or Repository are better candidates, as they are responsible for the so-called business logic of your app. So ideally change your ViewModel function to use `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` and then your fragment code can simply be:

```kotlin
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    courseViewModel.insertCourse(getData())
    Navigation.findNavController(it).popBackStack()
}
```

Now regarding your ViewModel, you say you're declaring it as:

```kotlin
class CourseViewModel(val repository: CourseRepository): ViewModel()
```

However, the default ViewModelProvider (which is what is used by `by activityViewModels()` and `by viewModels()` to create your ViewModel) will only instantiate a **zero argument** ViewModel, which explains the error you are seeing. (Side note: Google's current documentation of how all of this works is simply terrible; no nicer way to put it.)

If you want to keep the repository as an argument, then you need to create a custom [ViewModelFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory) so that the ViewModelProvider knows how to instantiate it. This Android Kotlin Fundamentals [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model) has an example of how to create one.

As an alternative to that, you can use dependency injection with Hilt and Jetpack, described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack).